# Conditional WHERE statement SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I would like to create a SP that will return all `Country` rows unless a `CountryID` is provided as a parameter. Here is how I imagined it might work, but it doesn't like it.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[usp_return_countries]
    @CountryID AS INT = 0
AS
BEGIN
        SELECT *
        FROM Countries
        WHERE Active = 1

        IF @CountryID > 0 BEGIN
            AND @CountryID = CountryID
        END

END
```

Thank you

P.S. I thought there might be a better way than simply repeating the entire SELECT statement based on the said condition.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try this, it's elegant :)

```
 ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[usp_return_countries]
   @CountryID AS INT = 0
 AS
 BEGIN

    SELECT *
    FROM Countries
    WHERE Active = 1
    AND (@CountryID = 0 OR @CountryID = CountryID)

 END
```

Comment: ah yes, of course. I seen this but got confused that it would match the table CountryID as 0. Perfect, thanks

Answer (score 6):

Easy enough to wrap up in a single `WHERE` clause:

```
SELECT * 
FROM Countries 
WHERE Active = 1 AND (@CountryID = 0 OR CountryID = @CountryID)
```

Answer (score 4):

Do it like this:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[usp_return_countries]
    @CountryID AS INT = 0 AS BEGIN

        IF @CountryID > 0 BEGIN
            SELECT *
            FROM Countries
            WHERE Active = 1
            AND @CountryID = CountryID
        END
        ELSE BEGIN
            SELECT *
            FROM Countries
            WHERE Active = 1
        END

END
```

Comment: So even if you have a massive select statement, you would have to repeat the entire thing for a additional condition?

Comment: @David this is more readable. If you want, you may choose a more elegant way like the other answers state. But remember, you can repeat the `select` but only one is really made :P

Comment: I did state I wanted something other than repeating the select statement. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Your approach may not be 'elegant' but it [may produce a better plan](http://sqlblogcasts.com/blogs/tonyrogerson/archive/2006/05/17/444.aspx).

Answer (score 3):

Something like this?

```
SELECT *
        FROM Countries
        WHERE Active = 1
AND
    (CountryID = @CountryID AND @CountryID <> 0) or (@CountryID = 0)
```